# Which is more likely: getting at least two heads in four coin flips, or getting at least three heads in five coin flips?

Tags: probability, statistics

The answer is, "At least 2 heads in 4 flips is much more likely than at least 3 heads in 5 flips" but i'm not sure how. Can someone explain why? I tried doing 1-(1/16)=94% and 1-(1/32)=99%, but that doesn't equal the answer.

Comment: It would help if you explained how you decided on those particular values so that someone can point out just where you went wrong in your approach to this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Two heads out of four flips has to be more likely than three heads out of five flips.  Imagine performing the flips in order.  Absolutely every time you score three heads out of five flips, you will have to start with at least two heads out of four flips.  And some of the times when you start with exactly two heads in the first four flips, the last flip will be a tail.  --Bob

Comment: Is there any way you can show this mathematically like I tried to do above? By calculating the chance?

Comment: Love the intuition of this answer.

Comment: @anonymousowl this *is* showing it mathematically, and in a much faster and more efficient manner than actually calculating the exact values for each.  Consider the question: "Which is more likely to happen: landing on at least two railroads when going around the board in a game of monopoly or landing on at least three railroads when going around the board in a game of monopoly?"  We don't *care* what the actual probabilities of each event are and it is tedious and difficult to find them.  But, the question only asked "which is more probable."

Comment: Here, we utilized the fact that the one event is a proper subevent of the other, directly implying that the one occurs with strictly higher probability.  While good practice to find the exact probabilities for your question since it is relatively small, there are going to be questions you encounter where doing things in the smart fashion and finding only the answer to the intended question without finding out any additional information beyond that is going to be much smarter to do.

Comment: This is mathematical: $P(\text{at least 2 of 4})=P(\text{at least 3 of 5}) + P(\text{exactly 2 of 5}\land\text{last of 5 is $T$})>P(\text{at least 3 of 5})$

Comment: @anonymousowl Don't confuse lack of formulas for lack of mathematics. It's a common misconception, and formulas are certainly often helpful, but when words get the job done, that is enough.

Answer (score 1):

In four flips, there are a total of $2^4=16$ outcomes, $11$ of which contain at least two heads.  In five flips, there are a total of $2^5=32$ outcomes, $16$ of which contain at least three heads.  As it turns out, $\frac{11}{16}>\frac{16}{32}$.

We come to the numbers $11$ and $16$ in the respective scenarios from the binomial theorem:

Let $n$ represent the number of coin flips and $h$ represent the number of heads.  The number of ways you can through $h$ heads in $n$ flips is $\binom{n}{h}$.  Thus, the probability of at least two heads in four flips is the sum of throwing two, three, or four heads in four flips, or 
$$\frac{\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{4}}{2^4}=\frac{6+4+1}{16}=\frac{11}{16}.$$
The probability of at least three heads in five flips is the sum of throwing three, four, or five heads in five flips, or
$$\frac{\binom53+\binom54+\binom55}{2^5}=\frac{10+5+1}{32}=\frac{16}{32}.$$

---

I would also like to point out that in this scenario,$$\sum_{h=\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil}^n\binom{n}{h}=\frac12\sum_{h=0}^{n}\binom{n}{h}$$ holds true for all odd $n$ (due to symmetry), and for even $n$ it will tend towards this value as $n\to\infty$.  For example, the probability of throwing at least $7$ heads in $13$ throws is the same probability of throwing at least $25$ heads in $49$ throws, and is the same probability of throwing $\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$ heads in $n$ throws for odd $n$.  For even $n$, taking data from a spreadsheet:

$$
\begin{array}
\ \textrm{at least}&\textrm{flips}&\textrm{probability}\\
10 & 20 &  0.588099\\
100 & 200 & 0.528174\\
1000 & 2000 & 0.508920\\
10000 & 20000 & 0.502821
\end{array}$$

As such, it remains good practice to be able to calculate, but being able to recognize patterns will make things much easier!

Comment: In fact, you can see by inspection that the probability of at least three heads in five flips has to be exactly $0.5$.  The probability of $k$ heads is exactly the same as the probability of $5-k$ heads.

Answer (score 1):

Using complementary probabilities is a reasonable idea, but it looks like you then made at least two errors when computing them.

Observe that the problem asks you to find the probabilities of **at least** two heads out of four and **at least** three heads out of five. So, in the first case, you’re looking for the probability of getting two **or** three **or** four heads. The complementary event is that you get zero **or** one head, so you need to compute the probabilities of each of those possibilities and add them up. It looks like you instead tried to compute the probability of getting *exactly* two heads and then subtracted it from $1$ to get the probability of *not* getting two heads. You have a similar error for the other probability: you’re computing the probability of *not* getting three heads out of five, which is not what the problem is asking about.

However, it also looks like you also made a mistake in computing the probabilities of exactly two out of four and three out of five: $1/16 = 1/2^4$ is the probability of getting a *specific* sequence of two heads and two tails, but you then have to multiply it by the number of such sequences. This is exactly what the binomial distribution covers: the probability of getting $k$ successes out of $n$ trials with an independent probability of $p$ for success in any individual trial is $\binom n k p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. So, the actual probability of getting two heads in four tosses is $\binom42\frac1{2^4} = \frac38$, six times what you have.

Putting this together, and using your idea of computing complementary probabilities, the correct probabilities are then $1-
\binom40\frac1{2^4}-\binom41\frac1{2^4}$ and $1-\binom50\frac1{2^5}-\binom51\frac1{2^5}-\binom52\frac1{2^5}$, which I’ll leave to you to calculate. It’s not that much more work in this case, however, to compute the two probabilities directly: they are $\binom42\frac1{2^4}+\binom43\frac1{2^4}+\binom44\frac1{2^4}$ and $\binom53\frac1{2^5}+\binom54\frac1{2^5}+\binom55\frac1{2^5}$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly calculate the probabilities. The probability of getting at least two heads in four flips can be calculated using the binomial distribution.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[\text{at least two heads]}&=1-\mathbb{P}[\text{exactly one head}]-\mathbb{P}[\text{exactly zero heads}]\\
&=1-\frac{4!}{1!(4-1)!}\cdot0.5^1\cdot(1-0.5)^{4-1}-\frac{4!}{0!(4-0)!}\cdot0.5^0\cdot(1-0.5)^{4-0}\\
&=1-0.25-0.0625=0.6875
\end{align*}
Using same method you can calculate the probability of getting at least three heads in five flips.