Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty\\ n\in\Bbb Z}\frac{\sum_{k=\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil}^{n}\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}=\frac {1}{2}$
Is the value of the limit I found numerically below correct ?
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty\\
n\in\Bbb Z}\frac{\sum_{k=\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil}^{n}\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}=\frac {1}{2}
$$
I found that this limit is $\dfrac {1}{2}$ for all odd values. But for even numbers it gets monotonically decreasing and approaching $\dfrac {1}{2}$. I tested it up to $100,000$. I need some mathematical background.

Does this help?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362426/convergence-of-probability-of-throwing-at-least-lceil-fracn2-rceil-heads-in

The limit is indeed $1/2$. For completeness sake, I'll reprove here that for odd values it goes to a half. Let
$$S_n=\sum_{k=\lceil n/2\rceil}^n\binom nk$$
We'll show that
\begin{align}S_{2m+1} &=2^{2m}\\\\S_{2m}&=2^{2m-1}+\frac12\binom{2m}m\end{align}
this is not hard to see, as by the symmetry of binomial coefficients we have
\begin{align}2S_{2m+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom {2m+1}k+\sum_{k=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}k\\\\&=2^{2m+1}\\\\S_{2m+1}&=2^{2m}\end{align}
Similarly
\begin{align}2S_{2m}&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom {2m}k+\sum_{k=m}^{2m}\binom{2m}k\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom {2m}k+\sum_{k=m+1}^{2m}\binom{2m}k+\binom{2m}m\\\\&=2^{2m}+\binom{2m}m\\\\S_{2m}&=2^{2m-1}+\frac12\binom{2m}m\end{align}
This shows that for odd $n$, the limit is not only $1/2$, but the sequence is constant. For even $n=2m$, it's enough to show that
$$\lim_m\frac{\binom{2m}m}{2^{2m}}=0$$
There's plenty of ways to do this, for instance, by Stirling's approximation the numerator is asymptotic to $2^{2m}/\sqrt{\pi m}$. But there are also elementary derivations as well.

Another way of seeing this is noticing that $\binom{n}{k}2^{-n}$ is the probability of seeing $k$ heads when tossing $n$ independent coins. So $\sum_{k=i}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{-n}$ is the probability of seeing at least $i$ coins.
You are asking what's the probability of seeing at least half heads as $n \to \infty$. You probably have a good intuition why this must be $\frac{1}{2}$.
More technically, the average of Bernoulli variables(Binomial over $n$) approximately follows a normal distribution(you can show it using the suggested Sterling approximation, see here). If $K$ is your binomial, $\frac{K}{n}$ goes to a normal variable $X$ centered around $\frac{1}{2}$ in distribution.
$$P(K \geq \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil) = P(\frac{K}{n} \geq \frac{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil}{n}) \to P(X \geq \frac{1}{2})$$
